# Configure Grails to eager fetch one-to-one & many-to-one relationships by default

Tags: grails, grails-orm, eager-loading

How can I configure Grails / GORM to eager fetch all one-to-one & many-to-one relationships by default?

I do not want to eager fetch many-to-many or many-to-one relationships by default; those should still lazy fetch.

I've seen how to specify eager fetch for individual relationships, but I haven't instructions for making it the default for one-to-one and many-to-one relationships.

Comment: Is fetchMode what you are looking for?though you will need to specify it per relationship,I am not sure if such default configuration is available ,which will apply to every relationship, including future changes .   http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/fetchMode.html .

Comment: I don't know the difference between static fetchMode = [xyz: 'eager'] & static mapping {xyz lazy: false}.  Do you?  Either way, I want to specify this as a default, instead of having to remember to set it for each relationship.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.